# Newbie working on PopClip extension - AppleScript not working

Tags: applescript

I'm working on my first PopClip extension using AppleScript. I'm getting the following error when trying to install the Extension:

**

Cannot Install Extension
The path /Users/myuserdirectoryname/Desktop/ReminderNote.popclipext does no contain a valid PopClip extension.

Reason: No such file: (null)

**

I have narrowed down the problem to my AppleScript info in the Config.plist. Or so I think. When I remove the following from the Config.plist file, the extension loads fine. When I add these two lines, the error returns.

```
<key>AppleScript File</key>
<string>ReminderNote.applescript</string>
```

My ReminderNote.popclipext package includes 3 files:

```
Config.plist,
 ReminderNote.applescript,
 ReminderNote.png
```

Here is the full Config.plist, in case that will help.

thanks for any tips or guidance -- jay

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>Extension Name</key>
    <string>ReminderNote</string>
    <key>Extension Identifier</key>
    <string>com.jel.ReminderNote</string>
    <key>Extension Description</key>
    <string>Create linked Reminder to Evernote using the selected text.</string>
    <key>Extension Image File</key>
    <string>ReminderNote.png</string>
    <key>Actions</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Reminder Note</string>
            <key>AppleScript File</key>
            <string>ReminderNote.applescript</string>
            <key>Image File</key>
            <string>ReminderNote.png</string>
            <key>Long Running</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I think this could be some kind of filesystem caching bug within PopClip. Try quitting PopClip and restarting it. Any improvement?

Comment: BINGO! That solved the problem. Thanks for the quick response Nick. Off to create many extensions....

Comment: It would be nice to move @NickMoore's comment to an answer and then could mark it as answered.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath could swear I did, but it seems to have disappeared.... I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be some kind of filesystem caching bug within PopClip. Try quitting PopClip and restarting it